# Is there a package that can calculate the Ricci tensor from a numerically given metric?

Tags: numerics, geometry, tensors

There are many packages about general relativity or differential geometry, and they can calculate the Ricci tensor from a symbolically given metric, for example, $g_{tt}=-f(r)$, $g_{rr}=h(r)$, etc.

However, if the metric is numerically given, for example, the numerical values of $f(r)$ are given for a grid of $r$, is there a package that can numerically calculate the Christoffel symbol, Ricci tensor, etc.?

Comment: The easiest way to do this in Mathematica would probably be to use `InterpolatingFunction`s to turn the grid data into functions that Mathematica can differentiate freely, and then feed those functions into the standard packages.  I'll see if I can mock up a demonstration of this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take your data and feed it into `Interpolation` to get something that Mathematica views as a continuous function.  As an example, let's look at a the metric for a spherically symmetric constant-density star (see Schutz's *A First Course in General Relativity*, §10.6).   This is an unrealistic model, but it has the advantage that there exists an analytic form for the metric that we can turn into a list of data.  Since it's unrealistic, let's make the star highly relativistic, with $M/R$ close to the limit value of 4/9.  We generate a list of the metric components at a list of radial coordinates $r$:

```
R = 1.; M = 0.4;
f[r_] = Piecewise[{{-(3/2 Sqrt[1 - 2 M/R] - 1/2 Sqrt[1 - 2 M r^2/R^3])^2, 0 <= r <= R}, 
    {-(1 - 2 M/r), r >= R}}, Indeterminate];
g[r_] = Piecewise[{{(1 - 2 M r^2/R^3)^-1,  0 <= r <= R}, {(1 - 2 M/r)^-1, r >= R}}, 
    Indeterminate];
fdata = Table[{r, f[r]}, {r, 0, 5 R, R/100}];
gdata = Table[{r, g[r]}, {r, 0, 5 R, R/100}];
```

`fdata` and `gdata` are now lists of numerical $\{r, f(r)\}$ or $\{r, g(r)\}$ pairs:

```
fdata[[1;;3]]
gdata[[1;;3]]

(* {{0., -0.0291796}, {0.01, -0.0291864}, {0.02, -0.0292069}} *)
(* {{0., 1.}, {0.01, 1.00008}, {0.02, 1.00032}} *)
```

Now we feed this data into `Interpolation` to get functions based on the numerical data:

```
finterp[r_] = Interpolation[fdata][r];
ginterp[r_] = Interpolation[gdata][r];
```

These functions can then be fed into whatever package you like to find the Christoffel symbols, Riemann tensor, etc.  For example, we can calculate the components of the Einstein tensor as
\begin{align*}
G_t {}^t &= \frac{1}{g} \left[ \frac{(g-1)}{r^2} + \frac{g'}{r g} \right] \\
G_r {}^r &= \frac{1}{g} \left[ \frac{(1-g)}{r^2} + \frac{f'}{r f} \right] \\
G_\theta {}^\theta =G_\phi {}^\phi &= \frac{1}{4 g} \left[ 2 \frac{f''}{f} - \left( \frac{f'}{f} \right)^2 + \frac{2}{r} \left( \frac{f'}{f} - \frac{g'}{g} \right) + \frac{f'g'}{fg} \right]
\end{align*}
We can plug in the expressions `finterp` and `ginterp` above:

```
Gtt[r_] := 1/ginterp[r] (-1/r^2 + ginterp[r]/r^2 + ginterp'[r]/(r ginterp[r]))
Grr[r_] := 1/ginterp[r] (1/r^2 - ginterp[r]/r^2 + finterp'[r]/(r finterp[r]))
Plot[{Gtt[r], Grr[r]}, {r, 0, 2 R}, PlotRange -> {-1,4}]
```

[image]

As expected, $G_t {}^t$ is roughly constant, since it is proportional to the density;  in fact, it should be equal to $8\pi \rho = 6 M/R^3 = 2.4$ in this example, which it is.  $G_r {}^r$ should be proportional to the pressure;  we see that the pressure also goes smoothly (more or less) from a non-zero central value to zero at the surface of the star.

Note that there's a bit of "glitching" at the surface of the star;  this glitching is worse for $G_{\theta} {}^\theta$ (not shown here), which should also be equal to the pressure.  This is just because $g'(r)$ is discontinuous in this model (since $m(r)$ is discontinuous.)  A more realistic model would not have this problem.  And, of course, there are errors at the origin $r = 0$ due to the coordinate singularity there.

I've done this for a particular case of a spherically symmetric metric;  however, this procedure could be pretty easily extended to an arbitrary metric expressed in an arbitrary set of coordinates.